# Calling classes in Swift to display drawRect

Tags: ios, class, swift

Basically, I have a class which contains the drawRect function that I am using to display a circular progress bar.

My issue is that I am unsure about how to display the progress circle? I have never worked with classes much before so I have no idea how I actually interact with the class.

Here is my code:

```
class ProgressCircle: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var progress: CGFloat = 0.7
    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.5

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
    var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFill").CGImage)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

}

I have this code above my SecondViewController class and I intend to display the circular progress bar within one of the views ('budgetDisplayView') in the second view controller.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Just add your custom view (ProgressCircle) to the view hierarchy and UIKit will take care of calling drawRect. For example in viewDidLoad add something like `self.view.addSubview(progressCircle)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me the error '(ProgressCircle).Type is not convertible to UIView'

Comment: I have a feeling you are confusing classes and objects, if it's definitely worth doing a quick course about OOP concepts. The line above should be preceded by something like 'let progressCircle = ProgressCircle()' to create an object, then the line above with the correct capitalization (progressCircle which is the instance, not ProgressCircle which is the class)

Comment: Although the progress circle is still not being displayed, your answer has made it make a bit more sense. I've actually just started a Computing Engineering course at University, so that should help me to understand OOP better pretty soon. Any ideas why nothing is being displayed?

Comment: Good luck with the course, I'm sure it will make a lot more sense soon. I can't see anything obvious about the above. Maybe the second last line is the problem, it might be drawing on top of the custom-drawn stuff and hide it. Have you tested this code and seen it render correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `ProgressCircle` just as subView.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

//or add where you want or an event
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   //give the appropriate frame
    var circle = ProgressCircle(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.budgetDisplayView.addSubview(circle)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this seems to give me a black screen.

Comment: this means your `progressCircle` is added.But may be it is not working as expected.You should check your `drawRect`.